# How to expose ImplicitCastExpr node in clang Python bindings?

Tags: python, clang, clang-ast-matchers

I have C code:

```c
int func4b(float *x, int (*fp)(int *hello, float *goodbye));

int hello(int *x, float *y) {
  return 0;
}

void callerb() {
  float x=6.0;
  func4b(&x, &hello);   // This is line 28
}

clang-12  -cc1 -ast-dump t2_calls.c 
provides:
   ...
   ...
   `-CallExpr 0x55ee03be4d68 <line:28:3, col:20> 'int'
      |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x55ee03be4d50 <col:3> 'int (*)(float *, int (*)(int *, float *))' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
```

Using clang's python bindings I get for this function call on line number 28:

```
CursorKind.CALL_EXPR func4b line=28 col=3
CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR func4b line=28 col=3
```

In my python code I am interested in knowing both that

1. this is node type "ImplicitCastExpr"   and
2. that functionCall's parameter signature is 'int (*)(float *, int (*)(int *, float *))'

Is this something that is possible to achieve w/ a few hour's work? I have been reading:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang  but that is about 9 years old, I was hoping that python bindings are now somehow more complete.